# After restar HBase ZooKeeper log Quorum.Learner: Got zxid 0x100000001 expected 0x1

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am performing some tests using HBase and Hadoop, I did setup a cluster with one master, two zookeeper and four region servers. Up until yestarday everything was working perfectly well, starting from today it simply don't start anymore.

When executing start-hbase all the process get alive:

1. HMaster using ports 8020 and 60010
2. HQuorumPeer using ports 2181 and 3888
3. HRegionServer

However when I take a look onto the server logs it seems the servers got stucked for some reason...

. HServer stop printing a WARNING about a native library that I was supposed to be using
 . HQuorumPeer on node 1 prints a WARNING about Getting a zxid 0x10000000001 expected 0x1
 . HQuorumPerr on node 1 has not print at all

Does someone has any idea on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am far, far away to be considered a hbase/hadoop expert. In fact it is just the first time I am playing around with it. Probably, the problem I had face was related to unproperly shutdown or corrupt file from the couple hbase/hadoop.

So here is my tip if you found yourself on the same situation:

- cleanup all hbase logs, in my case at $HBASE_INSTALL/logs/*
- cleanup all zookeeper data, in my case at /var/zookeeper/*
- cleanup all hadoop data, in my case at /var/hadoop/*
- cleanup all hdfs logs, in my case at /var/hdfs/log/*
- cleanup all hdfs namenode data, in my case at /var/hdfs/namenode/*
- cleanup all hdfs datanode data, in my case at /var/hdfs/datanode/*
- format your hdfs cluster typing the command hdfs namenode -format

**IMPORTANT:** Don't do that if you have data, you will probably loose all of it. I could do that once I am just using it for test purpose.

I will keep reading about hbase/hadoop in order to understand it better, anyway I can guarantee that is a tool far to be "*plug and play*" when compared to cassandra.

Hope this can help.

Regards